# Sorting the List after Sorting the Key

Tags: java, list, sorting

So I need to get a `List<Expense>` by a user, but that is ordered by descending Value of Expense. The method of Expense to get the Value is `getValue`. At the moment I'm only getting all the Expenses by each user, now I just need to order it. What I have is this:

```
public List<Expense> getListFactIndivValor() {
    TreeMap<String, List<Expense>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    Company c = new Company();
    for ( Expense e : c.getExpenses()) { 
        List<Expense> expenses = map.get(e.getTINUser());
        if (expenses == null) {
            expenses = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(e.getTINUser(), expenses);
        }
        expenses.add(e);
     }

    List<Expense> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : map.descendingKeySet()) {
        List<Expense> expenses = map.get(s);
        for ( Expense expense : expenses ) {
            result.add( expense);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sort your `Expense` by two properties at once, no need to populate `TreeMap`. This is kinda waste.

Try this:

```
public List<Expense> getListFactIndivValor() {
    List<Expense> expense = c.getExpenses();
    Collections.sort(expense, Comparator.comparing(Expense::getTinUser)
                                     .thenComparing(Expense::getValue));
    return expense;
}
```

Comment: All the expenses are in a Map<String, Expense> so i still need to get the expenses from the Map and pass them into the List... Not being able to do it though.

Comment: Never mind it's solved, was missing a new to initialize the ArrayList, my bad. Thank you very much.

Comment: In my function you do not need to init the `ArrayList` at all. Nevermind, glad it helped you

Comment: I needed because since expenses are saved in a Map, i couldn't simply do List<Expense> expense = c.getExpenses(); Had to pass the values of the map in a forEach and add them into the list. It's done anyways, that's what matters :)

Answer (score 0):

Expense needs to [implement Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You'll then need to [sort the list](https://reversecoding.net/java-8-comparator-how-to-sort-a-list/) at the bottom of your method before your return statement, like:

> expenses.sort(Comparator.comparing(Expense::getValue));

Hope that helps!

Comment: And how do implement Comparable on Expense? I've tried to just type after the class name as implement Comparable but it gives me an error because Expense is not abstract and cannot override method compareTo().

Comment: *shrug* if you update your post with your Expense class or point me to where I can find it, it's not difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the expenses list using a Comparator.

After you finish populating the treeMap (I'm not sure why you need a treemap here), you can do

```
return map.entrySet()
           .stream()
           .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
           .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), result -> result.stream()
                   .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Expense::getValue).reversed())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

It streams the entries of the map and flatMaps it since the value is a list and collects it into a list (as you do using the last `for` loop). Then it sorts the list using the passed `Comparator` which sorts the list in reversed order (`reversed()`) and again collects the result into a list.

Comment: Getting an error on collectingAndThen, saying: Required:java.util.stream.Collector<T,A,R>, java.util.function.Function<R,RR>    found: java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?, java.util.List<java.lang.Object>>, java.util.List<Expense>